# What is the difference between CALL and EXEC in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Consider:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE LowerCityDiscounts @city VARCHAR(45), @decrease DECIMAL(10,2) AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    UPDATE Customers SET discnt = discnt - @decrease
    WHERE Customers.city = @city;

    UPDATE Customers SET discnt = 0
    WHERE Customers.city = @city AND discnt < 0
    COMMIT;
END;
```

I tried to call this procedure with:

```
CALL LowerCityDiscounts 'Cleveland', 5;
```

but this only produces

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'Cleveland'.
```

Yet, if I change things to

```
EXEC LowerCityDiscounts 'Cleveland', 5;
```

everything works fine. This despite that [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa198007.aspx) stating that `call` is the right syntax.

Why does `EXEC` work when `CALL` does not?

Comment: The documentation linked relates to the ODBC driver, i.e. `CALL` is an ODBC construct.  You're using ODBC?

Comment: One is a tsql keyword, the other isn't basically

Comment: @KierenJohnstone: Well, I'm using ODBC inside the app, but I'm testing  things inside SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Ok then, as per my answer, the documentation you found is about ODBC drivers, and not SQL Server's Transact-SQL language

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yup.. `CALL` is an construct/syntax usable from an ODBC driver, as your documentation indicates.

There's no reference in the T-SQL documentation to `CALL`, only `EXEC`.

It doesn't work because it's not T-SQL.

Answer (score 5):

The T-SQL language does not recognise ODBC escape sequences; `EXEC` is the only command available for calling a stored procedure. ODBC escape sequences are interpreted by client-side libraries (e.g. ODBC, OLE DB, ADO, ADO.NET) and translated to real T-SQL syntax on the fly before execution.

The end result is, you can call your top-level stored procedure from the client using `CALL` if you want to, but if that procedure calls others, it must use `EXEC`.

The same principle applies for the date/time literal escape sequences.

Comment: `{ CALL [Foo] }` gets rewritten by the ODBC driver as `EXEC` before SQL Server sees it. The same doesn't seem to be true for the date/time literal escape sequences though. SQL Server does natively understand them as far as I could determine.

Answer (score 2):

I ran across an issue (while migrating databases) that MSSQL will accept `CALL` statement in a stored procedure - the SQL Management Studio complains but the query itself is executed successfully.

So a statement like this does execute:

```
create procedure spwho
as begin
    call sp_who2
end
go

exec spwho
```

Unfortunately even though the procedure is created, it does not produce any results (but neither does it produce any errors or warnings).

So in cases like this the `CALL` statement will not produce errors in MSSQL but anyway **should never used since it does not work**.