# Stored procedure doesn't preserve the table written, when called from Java app

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate, stored-procedures

I am looking for an answer for a small problem I have.   I think there is a theoretical concept I am not aware of.  Please help:

I have stored procedure that collects data from various tables and views. 'sp_getData()'

At various points, it writes the intermediate results to a 'table_A', by either INSERT or UPDATE.
At the end of stored procedure,
it outputs the data collected in 'tbl_A' with the simple select

```
select field1, field2, ..etc...
from tbl_A
where <someCondition is met>
```

tbl_A is static, and is supposed to keep the data in it after stored procedure ends.

If I run this stored procedure from SQLServer query analyzer - everything is fine, the table stays.  However if I call stored procedure from java application using Hibernate, the tbl_A is empty.  However, I DO GET RESULTS SET in Java application.

Here is the Java code part:

```
  private void execute(Session session, int port) throws MyCustomSystemException{
     String queryString = "{ call sp_getData(?) }";
    Query q;
    List resultList;
    try {
        q = session.createSQLQuery(queryString);
        q.setInteger(0, port);
        resultList = q.list();
    } 
    catch (HibernateException hex) {
         throw new MyCustomSystemException(
                "STYSTEM ERROR:  Can't execute    
                      sp_getData(?) procedure.",
                hex);
    }

    if (isSummaryReport())
        merge(resultList);
            System.out.println("==============") ;
    if (isFullReport())
        merge2(resultList);
   }
```

I am using Hibernate-Version: 3.1.3

merge() and merge2() are methods that process the data returned.  The contain no database related / hibernate code.

Can anyone help ???
Thank you.

Comment: Could it be that you have auto-commit ON when you run it through query analyzer, but OFF when you run it through your Java program?  Just a guess.

Comment: David, thank you very much for the tip.  That was it.  Apparently there were two hibernate.cfg.xml in a project, and only one was actually active.  I wasn't familiar with the project structure, but once I found the right config file, I made autocommit true and it worked.  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switching 
    call sp_getdata(?) 
to
    exec sp_getdata()

[Difference Between call and exec in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846418/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-exec-in-t-sql)